# Steps required to SSH into Azure Windows VM from a Linux VM

Tags: windows, azure, ssh, virtual-machine

Having created a Windows Azure VM and opened ports 3389 and 22 for inbound RDP and SSH connections, respectively.

I can successfully connect to the vm via RDP from a remote Windows PC.
Testing SSH connection in the Portal succeeds. However trying to connect from a remote Linux VM using SSH fails.

Given that SSH connection test within the portal succeeds, it suggests that (1) it is possible to SSH into a windows VM; and (2) there is no other config require on the server ie installing OpenSSH (or similar) / Copying over key file(s) to some location etc. However, the help steps in the Azure Portal for my Windows VM, for making remote SSH connections suggest that maybe a public key needs to exist on the server and that I need the private key on the LinuxVM I am trying to connect from.

Please could someone help me understand if ssh into windows Azure VM is possible and if so, the requirements / minimum set of steps (on the target Windows VM and the source Linux VM) I need to get to a state that I can successfully SSH.

Other posts re similar question posted have not helped me connect via ssh. I have not found a 'golden source of truth' on Microsoft docs. Maybe I missed it.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you manage to SSH into the Windows VM from the portal? Is there any guide?

Comment: Hi Ked. That is my question. How to setup, so that I can succeed with doing SSH from Linux to Windows .

Comment: Ahh ok my apologies, I overlooked that - `Testing` SSH connection in the Portal succeeds. I thought you meant testing it from the portal as in connecting to the Windows VM from another VM within Azure. Anyway, I'll update if I find anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A Windows Server doesn’t typically come pre-built and ready to go with SSH access and it requires some setup. You can follow [this](https://adamtheautomator.com/ssh-into-azure-vm/) to set up your Azure VM for SSH access. You can configure SSH on a Windows Azure VM for access, check out [How to Set Up OpenSSH on a Windows Server](https://adamtheautomator.com/openssh-windows/). After deploying the OpenSSH, you can follow the steps about **connect via SSH with client** in the Azure portal on your Linux client to access that Windows VM via SSH.

Comment: Thanks, Nancy. I was beginning to suspect this as could not find OpenSSH on the server.  The connection test for SSH is a little misleading (to me, at least).